# output all images from a directory - php

Tags: php, image

I'm trying via php to pull all images from a directory and print them as `< li < img src="url..` etc...

After doing a bit of research on SO, i found that the glob function should serve this purpose well, but i can't get it to work unfortunately. I think the problem is with me trying to echo the ID in the path? but being a bit of a newbie i can't seem to see my error.

```
    <? 
        $dirname="images/companies/";  
        echo '$current['id']';
        $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");

        foreach($images as $image) {
            echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: What makes a MySQL question of this? What exactly does "not work"?

Comment: What's the value of `$current['id']`? Remove the echo and concatenate the variable.

Comment: var_dump $current so we can have an idea of what it is

Answer (score 2):

You have no dir separator between `$dirname."*.jpg"`, so unless your `$current['id']` ends in a slash, glob won't work.

Try replacing `$dirname."*.jpg"` with `$dirname."/*.jpg"`.

Also: your `$dirname` is relative to the current PHP working directory. To make sure that this works regardless of where PHP was called from, use `$dirname=dirname(__FILE__)."/images/companies/".$current['id']`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure thar $dirname is relative to the current path or use absolute paths, e.g.:

   $dirname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../some/path/images/companies/";
2. Make sure that your path is not missing a slash, it would if $current['id'] had no trailing slash, that you had to write:

   $images = glob($dirname."/*.jpg");

Comment: Thanks guys! things are moving in the right direction now, the only problem i'm having is the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] seems to be returning "/home/iwth/public_html/images/companies/000383/1.jpg" where i require it to output just "/images/companies..." etc 

with dirname(__FILE__) i can't seem to get anything returned, but i get the same issue as above if i use dirname(__DIR__)

Answer (score -2):

Thaths the problem when oyu just steal code, but dont understand what it does.

If you want to scan a directory, you can use scandir(), which returns an array containing all the files it found, e.g.

```
$files = scandir("your/path/");
```

To show them, you simply use print_r(), its ugly and not formatted, but it does its purpose, if you want more, use echo and html/css:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
echo "</pre>";
```

No finished code, think a bit for yourself.

Comment: Why do you think glob() is not able to do this? The first example in the documentation shows nearly exactly the same use case..

Comment: I suspect you don't have the faintest idea of what [glob()](http://php.net/glob) does...

Comment: True, i had something else in my head, i thought it would return only directorynames, no filenames. Sry about that.